# How can I get started with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know what packages/web services I Should download to get started with PHP and MySQL. I am a beginner in both PHP and MySQL, so this will be my first time.

I am using Windows 7 ULTIMATE

Comment: Please use the search feature of SO, or look at the right side of this question under "Related". Such a question is often asked.

Comment: The packages depend on the OS you are running, so this question isn't answerable in its current state even if it didn't duplicate any others.

Comment: For very basic stuff: http://www.w3schools.com - Or a Google search.

Comment: @Lekensteyn, Thanks but I searched and i didnt understand anything

Comment: @βӔḺṪẶⱫŌŔ I would not recommend w3schools.

Answer (score 2):

[XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) is a perfect choice if you want to start. It works on Windows and has good [documentation](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/faq-xampp.html).

It will give you a web server (Apache), PHP, MySQL, phpMyAdmin, OpenSSL and several other useful tools. It is easy to manage and set up.

Comment: In professional websites, what editor do they use for building powerful PHP websites like facebook.

Comment: The editor is a different question. Everyone uses the editor they prefer, from simple text editors to complete IDEs. Concerning the web server setup, for a beginner this is a very good start. I don't suggest going for building powerful things like Facebook in the beginning, start with simple projects, earn the experience.

Comment: @user478636 don't think they use php on facebook :)

Comment: @Catalin For certain parts and in a certain way, they do.

Comment: @Catalin: yes they certainly do.

Comment: @bazmegakapa agree with you, but I bet the core is not PHP...or who knows :)

Comment: @Catalin http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/358/

Comment: @bazmegakapa nice, 10x for the info :P

Answer (score 2):

You can download [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (Windows Apache MySql and PHP package) that as it names implies contains Apache ,MySql and PHP and install them on your machine very easily.

You can download [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) that's an open source and powerful IDE.

There are a lot of EBooks and resources out there to learn PHP you can find a list on amazon [here](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=PHP&x=0&y=0).There's also [this site](http://www.phpvideotutorials.com/) that contains some tutorial videos discussing how to build web sites using PHP and MySql .

Comment: @Hannes XAMPP includes more things than WAMP, and can also run on different operating systems. Read the specs on both, and you can decide which one suits you better. Both are good.

Comment: @bazmegakapa  nah just curious , I'm a LAMP guy

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to buy [Head First PHP & MySQL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596006303), an extremely good book for beginners, you can learn a lot! All the packages/downloads required are all mentioned in the book.

Answer (score 0):

You should try http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html ...it's verry easy to install and get on coding :)

You could always try installing Virtual Box with Ubuntu on it and have all the benefits of linux PHP :P ... here's how: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox ; http://www.ivankristianto.com/os/ubuntu/howto-install-apache-php-mysql-and-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu/1027/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a editor such as Eclypse, Aptana, Dreamweaver I would suggest using Notepad++,
it has pretty much all you need and since its very light you won't have the damn long loading times to boot the program.
other than that have a look at http://w3schools.com and http://tizag.com, those will teach you the basics.
once you got those http://php.net will pretty much provide you with any info you need.